# yii active record error in getting unique data

Tags: activerecord, yii, model

How do I correct this error? I am using Yii but I am facing a problem in getting the unique domain with no path.

```
Error: Property "Promotions.getmBaseUrl" is not defined.
```

Data inside table:

```
            example.com/a/ggd.html
            example.com/b/hdgg.html
            assiggnmenthelp.net/page.html
            stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=yii
```

I want to get unique domain to display in view.

Output should be

```
            example.com
            assiggnmenthelp.net
            stackoverflow.com
```

But this code is not working as expected.

Code:

```
 private function getmBaseUrl($url)
 {
    LUrl::getBaseUrl($url); 
 }
public function getfiftyUrl() 
{
  $crt = new CDbCriteria; 
  $crt->select = "$this->getmBaseUrl(t.website)"; 
  $crt->order = 'id DESC'; 
  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array( 'criteria' => $crt,'pagination' => array( 'pageSize' => 10, ), ));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add code.                                                                                  private function getmBaseUrl($url){
        LUrl::getBaseUrl($url);
    }
    
        public function getfiftyUrl() {
        $crt = new CDbCriteria;        
        $crt->select = "$this->getmBaseUrl(t.website)";
        $crt->order = 'id DESC';

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $crt,          
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ),
        ));
        
    }

Comment: **The edit should be approved.** (The edit to this question has received 2 rejects and 2 approvals.)

Comment: Are those two methods written in a same file ? I think the error is due to the runtime access of `private function getmBaseUrl($url)`, eventhough it should have a return statement which actually returns a string for `CDbCriteria->select`

Comment: Try :   $crt->select = "$this->getmBaseUrl(t.website)";  Try to remove the quotes.